# Selective chemical absorbent for N2 gas removal

Tags: nitrogen, absorbant

Are there any chemical absorbants for selective  N2 removal from a gaseous mixture ?

I am thinking of something similar to say Pyrogalkol for O2 removal or KOH for CO2 etc.

Of course, N2 being relatively inert I can imagine this would be rather hard but still.

The particular application requires removal of small amounts of N2 ( say  less than 1% ) from a gas stream that is mostly Helium.

Alternatively an adsorbent bed is also an option. But do we have adsorbants that would selectively trap N2 but not He?

Otherwise a cryogenic condensor seems the only option? Any other ideas?

Comment: There is probably possible to have a molecular sieve, based on molecule geometry, similarly as is used for oxygen (as alternative to cryoseparation). (Big molecules do not fit, small ones do not stay).

Comment: @Poutnik Anyone know if such a Molecular sieve or zeolite is commercially available? I could not find any.

Comment: Why do you want to remove 1% $\ce{N2}$ from helium?

Comment: My Google is not better than yours, sorry.

Comment: Why not to use helium of guaranteed sufficient purity? // I assume using metallic lithium to form Li3N is not applicable.

Comment: The great thing about cryogenics is (a) there is no component that gets “used up” and requires reactivation or replacement and (b) it removes practically any non-He contaminant, thus solving possible future problems before they happen.

Answer (score 3):

There are [various techniques](https://www.quantum-technology.com/purify/room-temp-purification.html) to trap $\ce{N2}$ by adsorption in a molecular sieve, or behind a semi-permeable membrane, rather than chemically combining it.

Though one could do as [Cavendish, Rayleigh and Ramsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon) did, reacting the nitrogen with added oxygen in an electrical arc and absorbing the reaction products, or use a metal [getter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter), as used in radio tubes (valves, if you prefer), those would be inefficient and costly.

look at this [ACS article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.iecr.7b00976) that discusses the economics of helium purification.